# jQuery Date picker to only select mondays

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following jQuery which gives me the current date and the populates the enddate 7 days from the selected date. I would like for the user to only be able to select mondays from the datepicker. Can this be done the way in which I have my code?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#WeekCommencing").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
            minDate: 0,
           // MondayOnly: function(date){ return[(date.getDate() == 1),""];},
            onSelect: function (date) {
                var date2 = $('#WeekCommencing').datepicker('getDate');
                date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 7);
                $('#WeekEnding').datepicker('setDate', date2);
                //sets minDate to dt1 date + 1
                $('#WeekEnding').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
            }
        });
        $('#WeekEnding').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
            onClose: function () {
                var dt1 = $('#WeekCommencing').datepicker('getDate');
                console.log(dt1);
                var dt2 = $('#WeekEnding').datepicker('getDate');
                if (dt2 <= dt1) {
                    var minDate = $('#WeekEnding').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                    $('#WeekEnding').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add as function name `beforeShowDay`

```
beforeShowDay : function(date){ return[(date.getDay() == 1),""];}, //Monday Only Function
```

and that should work.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul I replaced my line of code `MondayOnly: function(date){ return[(date.getDate() == 1),""];},` with your suggestion but now the datepicker has no days at all that I can select http://prntscr.com/akcb0g

Comment: My bad. It should be `date.getDay()` not `date.getDate()`. See the updated answer.